# Could not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, android

I am a new Android learner, and I am making my first Android app for a language translator. After adding some dependencies I am having some issue. How can I solve this?

> Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.                 Could not determine artifacts for android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1: No cached version available for offline mode                 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2s 719ms)

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb5eX.png)

Comment: Please provide a plain text of your code that can be edited not a picture

Comment: Improve gramar and format

Answer (score 0):

First try to update all your dependencies since you are working online now. Android studio  provides a feature that when you hover over a dependency in the apps build.gradle file, it recommends latest dependencies for you to upgrade to. After doing that then you go to file on the menu bar then to settings like this 
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Gradle
You uncheck offline mode in the global gradle settings